# GMP - Certain Functions not declared, others are? C++/MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, gmp

In windows 'm building a C++ project that I have working in Linux that uses the GMP library. I am using the precompiled static MinGW library and include files from here - http://cs.nyu.edu/~exact/core/gmp/index.html

Everything seems to go well (mpz_init, mpz_mul, etc.) except when I get to mpz_powm_sec().

```
mpz_powm_sec(m, c, d, n);
```

That line gives:

```
error: 'mpz_powm_sec' was not declared in this scope
```

Yet none of my other references to GMP do. Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to make it compile?

Answer (score 1):

The official website for GMP is https://gmplib.org/. The version you downloaded from that third-party website is more than 12 years old, the library has evolved quite a bit since then.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the official GMP website at https://gmplib.org, the canonical source for precompiled binaries for use with MinGW.org's compiler tool chain is the SourceForge repository at https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/; the latest MinGW build of GMP is https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gmp/gmp-5.1.2/, (you will need the "-dev" package, for headers and import libraries, and likely the "-dll" for runtime bindings).

If you use binaries which have been prepared by the MinGW developers themselves, they will have been tested in conjunction with MinGW; if you grab third party builds, they may well be out of date, may not work, and you're pretty much on your own.